# Can I enter the UK with short term study visa even though my course is over?

Tags: visas, uk, international-travel, study, palestine-citizens

I was enrolled in a student exchange program for a two-week internship at a university in the UK, but unfortunately my visa's processing got delayed, and I received my passport with visa too late and missed the course. I hold a Palestinian passport.

Now I'm thinking to use my visa to enter the UK again this summer ,to attend a conference. I'm afraid that I would get rejected since my visa was approved for study, and the course that I was attending has finished.

Is there a risk in attempting, or I can enter the uk with no troubles? I do have the visa, but it's a short-term study visa, Type C.

Comment: This would count as "change of purpose" from studying to attending a conference. On arrival in the UK, the Immigration Officer would query why you did not arrive in the UK near the start date of your Visa - this would lead you to explaining there is a "change of purpose". This could invalidate your Visa. What nationality passport do you hold?

Comment: Palestinian passport , isn't there any legal spot which would help me get in without getting a new visa ? because sadly i already bought the ticket not knowing such thing would happen

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely a risk attached to trying to use a short-term study visa granted for a specific internship to enter the UK as a visitor to attend a totally unconnected conference.

Immigration Rule 321A (1) provides that a person’s leave to enter may be cancelled at port or while the holder is outside the UK if there has been a change in circumstances 
https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-9-grounds-for-refusal

It would be advisable to contact the embassy that issued your visa to ask if your change of purpose of travel is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you sir , i'll surely do try to contact them.